# Showing Overall Description on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a UI where more than three div's are there which has the data's with different ids but with the common button called as "Read".I have displayed the messages in which I have kept the message body as a tiny(15) on this Read button it show me the entire body of the message.How to achieve this one way that I am trying to do is as follows:

```
foreach (var item in Model.MyNote)
    {

    <div class="row">
        @if (item.Owner.Roles.Any(cx => cx.RoleName == "Customer"))
        {
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="three columns">
                        <img src="@Request.Url.FormatAbsoluteUrl(@item.Owner.Personal.ImageURL)" />
                        <span style="text-align: center;">
                            @item.Owner.Personal.FirstName  @item.Owner.Personal.LastName
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nine columns">
                        <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" id="messid" />
                        <p class="parahide1">@item.Description </p>
                        <p class="parahide">@item.Description.ToTiny(15) </p>
                    </div>
                    @*<a href="@Url.Action("Read", "Appointment", new { @id = item.Id })" class="button" id="read">Read</a>*@
                    <button class="button" id="read">Read</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else if (item.Owner.Roles.Any(cx => cx.RoleName == "Professional"))
        {

            <div class="panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="nine columns">
                        <p>@item.Description </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="three columns">
                        <img src="@Request.Url.FormatAbsoluteUrl(@item.Owner.Professional.ImageURL)" />
                        <span style="text-align: center;">@item.Owner.Professional.CompanyName</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Read", "Appointment", new { @id = item.Id })" class="button">Read</a>
            </div>                                                  
        }
    </div>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".parahide1").hide();
        $("#read").live('click',function () {
            $(".parahide").hide();
            $(".parahide1").show();
        });
    });
</script>

    }
```

This give the the result but it is showing the description of all the div's even if I click on the button of the first div.

Comment: .live() is deprecated , use .on() instead

Comment: no i am getting the same result

Comment: what my thinking says that this foreach is looping for say 3 times but the element are having the same class at each time of execution of loop..so can we append something with the id in $(".parahide").hide();
        $(".parahide1").show();

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the classes in the parent of the current button like this -

```
$(function () {
    $(".parahide1").hide();
    $("#read").on('click',function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".parahide").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".parahide1").show();
    });
});
```

Hence, only the `div`s present in the current button's parent will be hidden or shown!

More on [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Also use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of .live() as live has been deprecated.

Comment: Using `on` will require at least jquery 1.7. Since `live` is working, an older version of jquery is used and needs to be upgraded!

Comment: Yep. And better to upgrade and use than use the deprecated one.

Comment: can we do something like this $(".parahide1"+ @item.Id+ ").hide();

Comment: You can, but I don't think there's a need to if you use the above "parent" method.

Comment: to differentiate the divs

Comment: but parent is applied to the first element only not for others..why is it so?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "parent is applied"